# Cybersource simple order api sample application gives "The type initializer for 'CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature' threw an exception."

Tags: c#, soap, payment

I was running the simple order api sample application using SOAP which we can download from Cybersource official website. I changed the merchantid and securitykey path as per documentation . But wheneve I run the application im getting error

> "The type initializer for 'CyberSource.WSSecurity.Signature' threw an exception."

I browsed through various post, but nobody tells clearly what to do . I have installed MS WPE 3.0 but still getting same error.

Comment: You need to look at the details in the exception - in particular, there should be an InnerException which makes it clear what the *cause* of the type initializer failure is.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, Please help us ...

Comment: @Mridul Raj, did u resolved this issue

Comment: @satishkumar . Yes I got it resolved . Check my answer and see if its helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved after i generated a new soap-toolkit key from cyber-source business center and used it in my application .

Answer (score 1):

The web server does not have the Microsoft WSE 3.0 addon installed.

Install the MS WSE 3.0 addon on the server.  That is a free download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=018A09FD-3A74-43C5-8EC1-8D789091255D&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thnaks for the respone. But I had mentioned that, MS WSE 3.0 is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally if you are trying to use this on something newer than XP/Win 2003 and using iis7 or above:  make sure your app pool has Enable 32-bit Applications as TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, I downloaded new Security Keys for the SOAP Toolkit API and changed the Project properties to Build->Target Platform to X86. It worked